# Which theorem is this? If $\phi(x)$ is differentiable at $0$, then there exists $\psi(x)$, continuous at $0$, such that $\phi(x) = \phi(0) + x\psi(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question, distribution-theory

I'm self studying generalized functions, and it's been the third time or so that I come across the following statement :

> If $\phi(x)$ is differentiable at $0$, then there exists a function $\psi(x)$ continuous at $0$ such that $\phi(x) = \phi(0) + x\psi(x)$.

Which theorem or result is used here? Is there a higher order version (i.e. in the case where $\phi$ is twice differentiable or more).

At first I used to tell myself it's kind of like a taylor expansion, say :

$$\phi(x) = \phi(0)+x\phi'(0) + x^2\epsilon(x)$$

but then $\phi'(0)+x\epsilon(x)$ is not guaranteed to be defined at $0$; well, if it were, then we'd have the continuity at $0$ due to $\lim_{x \to 0} \epsilon(x) = 0$.

Comment: By generalized functions do you mean distributions?

Comment: @N.S. yes. the book I use is called 'Generalized Functions : Theory and Applications'

Comment: $\phi$ bounded (continuous) means $\psi(x)=\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x}$ is bounded (continuous) for $x \ne 0$ and $\phi$ differentiable at $0$ means $\psi(x)$ is continuous at $0$.

Comment: I believe that's Caratheodory's formulation of differentiability( at 0). From my undergrad classes, I know its equivalent to being differentiable (at 0) but I can't find a source. There is some discussion here https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/60c9z7/why_isnt_the_caratheodory_derivative_more/?st=jrfiizeq&sh=4c170ece

Comment: This has further details and references as well as sketches of e.g. how this is equivalent to a Frechet derivative in Banach spaces 

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2321000/a-new-definition-of-derivative

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\phi(x) = \phi(0) + x\psi(x) \Leftrightarrow \\
\psi(x)= \frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x-0} \forall x \neq 0$$

$\phi$ is differentiable at $x=0$ if and only if 
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \psi(x)= \phi'(0)$$

In order to make $\psi$ continuous at $x=0$ you need to define $\psi(0)$ such that 
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \psi(x)= \psi(0)$$

**SOOO** You know what $\psi(x)$ should be for $x \neq 0$ and what $\psi(0)$ should be.

Comment: oh I see, extension by continuity. so we could've also defined $\psi$ for non-zero $x$'s the way I thought in the 1st place using taylor expansion and at $0$ we'd just put the limit of that same function and then we'd get the same $\phi'(0)$. thanks.