# A definition of differentiable functions for arbitrary topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, definition, big-picture

### **Background**

It is well-known that there is no notion of derivative for **arbitrary** topological spaces. However while investigating the notion of derivative as we find in one variable real analysis I came to generalize the notion. I am now wondering what properties must this notion of "differentiable function" satisfy in order to become a "good" enough definition.

Our motivation for the formulation of this definition is mainly [Caratheodory's definition of derivative](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CaratheodoryDerivative.html).

### **The Definition**

Before going straight into the definition itself, let me mention at the outset that this question is a revised version of [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/332653/a-definition-of-differentiable-functions-for-arbitrary-topological-spaces) deleted MO question.

Let us first consider a certain special case of the definition in the following,

> **Definition 1.** Let $R$ be a field and $\tau_1,\tau_2$ be any two topologies on $R$. A continuous function $f:R\to R$ will be said to be $(\tau_1,\tau_2)$-differentiable on $R$ at $a\in R$ iff there exists a function $g:(R,\tau_1)\to (R,\tau_2)$ such that,
>
> $$g(x):=\begin{cases}\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}&\text{if}~x\ne a\\L&\text{else} \end{cases}$$for all $x\in R$ and $g$ is continuous at $a$.

We can generalize the above definition as follows,

> **Definition 2.** Let $X,Y$ be arbitrary topological spaces. Let $g_a:X\to Y\times Y\times X\times X$ be the function defined by, $$g_a(x):=(f(x),f(a),x,a)$$for all $x\in X$. A function $f:X\to Y$ is said to be *differentiable at $a\in X$ with value in a topological space $Z_a$ with respect to a function $$\psi_a:f(X)\times \{f(a)\}\times X\setminus\{a\}\times \{a\} \to Z_a$$* iff there exist a unique continuous function $$\Phi_a:f(X)\times \{f(a)\}\times X\times \{a\} \to Z_a$$such that $\Phi_a\circ g_a$ is continuous at $a\in X$ and $$\Phi_a\Big|_{f(X)\times \{f(a)\}\times X\setminus\{a\}\times \{a\}}\equiv \psi_a$$

For example, if $X=Y=Z_a=\mathbb{R}$ (equipped with usual topology) and $f$ is differentiable at $a\in \mathbb{R}$ with, $\psi_a: f(X)\times \{f(a)\}\times X\setminus\{a\}\times \{a\} \to Z_a$ defined as follows,

$$\psi_a\Bigl(f(x),f(a),x,a\Bigr)=\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$ We may then define $\Phi_a: f(X)\times \{f(a)\}\times X\times \{a\} \to Z_a$ as follows,

$$\Phi_a\Bigl(f(x),f(a),x,a\Bigr)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} &\text{if}~x\ne a\\ f'(a)&\text{else}\end{cases}$$

### **Some Remarks**

- It was pointed out to me by [Alexander Schmending](https://mathoverflow.net/users/46510/alexander-schmeding) in a comment below the deleted MO post which I have mentioned earlier that [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0723086904800069) is related to my query although he explicitly mentioned that the framework of the paper is restrictive than what I want in this post. I have briefly read the paper and indeed found the approach of the paper to be based on the same idea of generalizing [Caratheodory's definition of derivative](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CaratheodoryDerivative.html) to more general setting. However even after reading the paper I found no obvious way of generalizing the approach of the authors to arbitrary topological spaces.
- Regarding the specific nature of relationship between $f$ and $\Phi_a\circ g_a$, what I have in mind is something like the following: if $f$ is differentiable at $a$ then $(\Phi_a\circ g_a)(a)$ denotes the value of **a** derivative of $f$ at $a$ with value in $Z_a$. (If we want **a** derivative of $f$ at $a$ we may impose the restriction that $Z_a$ be Hausdorff.)

### **Question**

- What properties should this notion of differentiable function must have so that it is a "good" enough definition of differentiable functions?
- How should I go about formulating a notion of derivative of $f$ at $a$ with value in $Z_a$?

Comment: Is there a Caratheodory's definition of derivative in higher dimension (say, for function $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$)?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1267268/why-cant-differentiability-be-generalized-as-nicely-as-continuity)

Comment: In Definition 1, you work on a division ring. Noting that a division ring is not necessarily commutative, then the fraction $\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ is ambiguous. You may write it like $(x-a)^{-1}(f(x)-f(a))$ or $(f(x)-f(a))(x-a)^{-1}$ as left or right fractions.

Comment: @Qurultay: Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @ArcticChar: See **Definition 3** of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2321000/a-new-definition-of-derivative).

Comment: Requiring $g$ be continuous at $a$ rules out functions that are differentiable but not continuously differentiable. Is this desired?

Comment: @eyeballfrog: Yes. Absolutely.

Comment: @PhoemueX: I have edited the question a bit. I hope this is now clearer.